# Trying to upload an image to Microsoft Azure api with NodeJS, rather than JQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am trying to upload an image for Microsoft Azure text recognition, but I only see support for a jquery submission.

I have a Raspberry Pi taking a picture with a NodeJS app (pi-camera).  Then, I want to send this to the Azure api with that same app.  Is there any support for this?  I doesn't seem efficient to create a web page and open a browser to navigate to a picture, when I have a node app running.

The actual goal is to take a picture of my water meter with my Raspberry Pi, and then upload the image to have the number read and returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: an API normally just responds to a HTTP request. There's generally no particular requirement about how that request is created (although some may not support CORS requests). What do you mean by "only support for a jQuery submission" (by which I assume you really mean AJAX)? Where did you read that? NodeJS has libraries which help you make HTTP requests, just like almost every other modern language. Check the API's documentation and construct a HTTP request which conforms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments.  I guess my question was - how to handle the local file, as opposed to give Azure a URL.  I just got it to work with a different strategy.  I used the 'request' and 'fs' libraries in conjunction, where I used fs.createReadStream to load the file.